# Create new Products in Database once we click on button from product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, database, javascript

We are displaying "**SAVE DESIGN**" button in [Product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html). once Registered customer click on that button, **we want to create new product with same product details with different [ random] sku.**  we want to display those products in custom tab under "My account" similar to "My wishlist".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not a full solution, but some puzzle pieces you can put together.
There should already be a lot of scripts out there to create a product programattically. 
Here is just one [from inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/) but you can look for others.

What you have to change.

You need to set the random SKU.

```
$sku = call your method to generate the sku.
$product->setSku($sku);
```

And you could add a new product attribute that is a reference to the customer id.

Let's say the attribute is called `created_by_customer_id`.

You will have to get the customer id from the session and set it on the product before calling `save`.

```
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);
```

And to display the products in the customer account you need to add a new [menu item to account navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1977824/2047249).

And in the controller action that is linked to the menu can load a block that gets the products collection associated to the current user.

```
public function getCustomerProducts() 
{
    $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('created_by_customer_id', $customerId);
    return $products;
}
```

The template is up to you.
You can just loop through the products:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getCustomerProducts() as $product) :?>
    <!-- your html here -->
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Those `puzzle pieces`  are valuable as diamonds..... you are the ultimate.....