# icon is not clickable in product view page , but working in listing page

Tags: magento-1.9

we are using below code in **product listing page**, once customer **click on icon** present on listing page [list.phtml] , than it saving that product in database & displaying under My Product likes. but same code is not working in **product view page** [view.phtml]

[image]

**In view page icon is not clickabe** as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

icon

[image]

code : list.phtml / view.phtml

```
<?php if($customerId){?>
   <?php if($customerlikeProduct=="No"){?>
         <img id="img-<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>" 
         onclick="saveproductLike('<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>','<?php echo $customerId?>','<?php echo count($likeProduct)?>');" 
         src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl($customerlikeProductimage) ?>"/>    
         <?php }else{?>
              <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl($customerlikeProductimage) ?>"/>
   <?php } ?>
<?php } else{?>

<!-- Code for Guest -->
```

list.phtml : http://pastebin.com/8dEUaXuP

View.phtml : http://pastebin.com/9RrCe3D2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your product view page and product list page for the `div` which you are using are actually present or not.

For example: I have found that, you are using java script function:

`setproductlogin(pid)` and this function triggers click event on `div` with `id('productlistlogin')`. But this `div` is not present on your product view page.

Comment: we have this script `function setrequestlogin()
 {
   //jQuery("#productlistlogin").trigger("click");
 } `   in list.phtml, i updated same in `product.phtml` , still icon is not cickable in product view page.....

Comment: also i updated question with complete code of `list.phtml & view.phtml` , please check once.....

Comment: thanks a lot , welcome to community, we need developers like you....

Comment: Thank you. for appreciation.
Now your product view page has started showing login popup. Just some design issue is left.

Comment: ya, thats right, i will work on design after i complete [this one](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163039/create-new-products-in-database-once-we-click-on-button-from-product-view-page)